# Authentication with google plus on Ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic4, google-plus

I'm creating a login and signup page on Ionic 4 and I'm trying to authenticate with google plus and then send the auth data to my rails application (backend).

But when I try to login, I get an error code '10', that according to google:

> The application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as fatal. The developer should look at the logs after this to determine more actionable information.

But I can't find where is the error.

So what I did untill now was:

1. Create firebase android project with my package name
2. Create a digital SHA-1 and add to the project
3. Add cordova google plus plugin

login.ts

async doGoogleLogin(){

```
this.googlePlus.login({
  'scopes': '',
  'webClientId': 'myWebClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'offline': true 
}).then(user =>{
  this.saveGoogleUser(user);
  this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
}, err =>{
  this.presentAlert("Error Console", err);
}); 
}
```

When I click on login button, it's open the google page, but when I click on an account, it closes the page and my alert shows ('10').

I'm stucked on it :(

Comment: YOu know that google+ was shutdown sevral years ago and only works for Gsuite accounts now right?

Comment: Yeah, I think that it's just the name. The plugin allow authentication with google Sing-In. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus